# UIButtons squished on landscape and smaller devices

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, autolayout, uistackview

I have built out the UI for my application by nesting horizontal stack views inside of a vertical stack view. On the iPhone 8 Plus, the UIButtons are appearing as designed in both portrait and landscape orientations. Below is a screenshot of landscape orientation on the iPhone 8 Plus simulator.

[image: iPhone 8 Pls landscape]

The stack views are employing Fill Alignment with Fill Equally Distribution. The Content Mode for each of the buttons is set to Aspect Fit and when tested on a smaller device, the UIButtons become squished and they lose their aspect ratio. Below is a screenshot of landscape orientation on the iPhone SE simulator.

[image: iPhone SE landscape]

How can I prevent the squishing of the images from occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Image programmatically and set the **contentMode of button's imageView** as center or aspectFit.

```
settingsButton.imageView?.contentMode = .center
settingsButton.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "imagename"), for: .normal)
```

Or you can change your constraints of your UIButton and give aspect ratio 1:1 for height and width.

Comment: Stupid question, but would I implement this approach on the viewController that the buttons are located? I am super new to this.

Also, when I use the aspect ratio option in the constraints panel, the stack view changes size. Not sure why.

Comment: Would I treat the outlet as a computed property?

Comment: Yes, just take an individual outlet for each button and in viewDidLoad set the Images and not in storyboard.

Comment: Got it! Thank you :)